# C++ посоветуйте библиотеку для полнотекстового поиска

Tags: c++, поиск-библиотек, полнотекстовый-поиск

Можете посоветовать библиотеку для полнотекстового поиска на C++. Желательно, что бы она имела следующий функционал или его можно было бы добавить самостоятельно:

1. Что бы можно было искать точную фразу(например: "точна фраза")
2. Диакритические символы - что бы а и ā, например, считались одной буквой
3. Учитывала похожие по звучанию буквы(Например яйцо и йайцо)
4. Нужна поддержка разных операторов поиска:

   - кавычки для поиска точной фразы.
   - Операторы AND, OR, NOT, ?(для замены одного символа), *(для замены нескольких символов)
   - Поиск в пределах N слов в строгом порядке (Например: "a b c"/4) или не в строгом(Например: "a b c"@4)

Стоит ли использовать CLucene, если его очень давно не обновляли? Или лучше сразу смотреть на другие актуальные проекты?

Comment: Я знаю, что есть исходники Sphinx версий 2.X на гитхабе.

Comment: А вообще в открытом доступе мало хороший и полноценных поисковых движков.

Answer (score 2):

Выбрал LucenePlusPlus.
Для 2 и 3 пункта приходится индексировать данные несколько раз, удаляя из них диакритические символы и сохраняя их в разные поля(Сохранять в разные поля, что бы использовать эти функции опционально).
Для 1 пункта пришлось вообще не использовать анализатор и так-же сохранять в отдельное поле. Также пришлось доработать стандартный парсер запросов для использования этого поля.

upd: Вроде бы можно использовать PositionIncrementAttribute, что бы не индексировать несколько раз.